# Get value from textbox and save it in a text file or send it to an email address in PHP

Tags: php, html

I am a beginner in PHP and HTML and basically what I want to do is to have a few textboxes, and after the Submit button is pressed, the text introduced in those textboxes I want to be saved in a text file or to be sent to an email address. Can you help me out? I really have no idea about how to get this project started.

Thank you!

Comment: What you have searched so far?

Comment: I just created the HTML. I don't know what to use to save into a text file or send to email.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you should try something and after that come here if you have any issue . any way I can tell you some ways to do this

here are some links by which you can create a simple php form with email sending [link 1](http://www.freecontactform.com/email_form.php) [link2](http://www.123contactform.com/simple-php-contact-form.html) [link 3](http://www.html-form-guide.com/contact-form/simple-php-contact-form.html) [link form](http://www.phpeasystep.com/phptu/8.html)

to enter the content into file read [here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-put-contents.php)

basicaly the code is

```
<?php 
$action=$_REQUEST['action']; 
if ($action=="")    /* display the contact form */ 
    { 
    ?> 
    <form  action="" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data"> 
    <input type="hidden" name="action" value="submit"> 
    Your name:<br> 
    <input name="name" type="text" value="" size="30"/><br> 
    Your email:<br> 
    <input name="email" type="text" value="" size="30"/><br> 
    Your message:<br> 
    <textarea name="message" rows="7" cols="30"></textarea><br> 
    <input type="submit" value="Send email"/> 
    </form> 
    <?php 
    }  
else                /* send the submitted data */ 
    { 
    $name=$_REQUEST['name']; 
    $email=$_REQUEST['email']; 
    $message=$_REQUEST['message']; 
    if (($name=="")||($email=="")||($message=="")) 
        { 
        echo "All fields are required, please fill <a href=\"\">the form</a> again."; 
        } 
    else{         
        $from="From: $name<$email>\r\nReturn-path: $email"; 
        $subject="Message sent using your contact form"; 
        mail("youremail@yoursite.com", $subject, $message, $from); 


        echo "Email sent!"; 
        } 
    }   
?>
```

code to put content into file is

```
<?php
$file = 'people.txt';
// Open the file to get existing content
$current = file_get_contents($file);
// Append a new person to the file
$current .= "John Smith\n";
// Write the contents back to the file
file_put_contents($file, $current);
?>
```

Answer (score 2):

> Copy paste and see the result

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
    <html>
        <head>
            <title>Example</title>
            <style>

            </style>
        </head>
        <body>
            <form method="post">
                <pre>
                    Name <input type="text" name="name">
                </pre>
                <pre>
                    Email <input type="text" name="email">
                </pre>
                <pre>
                    <input type="submit" value="Submit" name="submit">
                </pre>
            </form>
        </body>
    </html>


    <?php
    $to = "somebody@example.com";
    $subject = "Subject of your email goes here";
    $txt = "Body of your email goes here!";
    $headers = "From: webmaster@example.com" . "\r\n" .
        "CC: somebodyelse@example.com";

    if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
        $name = $_POST['name'];
        $email = $_POST['email'];
        if($name != '' || $email != ''){
            mail($to,$subject,$txt,$headers); // Here your email is being sent.
            $myfile = fopen("newfile.txt", "w") or die("Unable to open file!"); // Here your file is being opened if it doesn't exist so it will create it first
            fwrite($myfile, "Name :".$name."&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;"."Email:". $email); // Here we are wirting file Name and email from the textboxes
            fclose($myfile);//closing the file
        }
    }
    ?>
```

Comment: Your code must be on live server for email. Email will not work from local.

Comment: we can send email from local host . Just need to add settings for that .

Comment: Yes you have to configure smtp on localhost for that

Answer (score 0):

this may help you to start

```
<form name=myform method=post action="same_page.php">
    <input type="text" name=username value="<?php echo $_POST['username'] "?>
    <input type="text" name=email value="<?php echo $_POST['email']?> >
    <input type="submit" value=submit>
    </form>
    <?php 
    $username = $_POST["username"]; //Email address you want it to 'appear' to come 
    $email = $_POST["email"]; 

    if(strlen($username) && strlen($email))
    {
         $mailText ="The Contact Details: <br>";
    }
                  $mailText=$mailText."<table border=1 cellspacing=0 cellpadding=0>";
                      while(list($Key, $Val)= each($_POST))
                       {
                        $mailText=$mailText."<tr><td width=50%>"; 
                        $mailText=$mailText."<b>".$Key."</b></td>";
                        $mailText=$mailText."<td width=50%>";   
                        $mailText=$mailText.$Val;
                        $mailText=$mailText."</td></tr>";  

                 }

    $to = "youremailid.com";
    if(strlen($username) && strlen($email))
    {
    $subject = "your subject"; //Subject Line
      $headers .= "From:yourmail.com\n";
        $headers .= "X-Sender:  yourheader.com\n";
         $headers .= "Content-Type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1\n";         // Mime type
    $mailforms = mail($to, $subject, $mailText, $headers);
    }
    ?>
```